# How to stop Gradle compilation after a preset number of errors

Tags: java, gradle

In Gradle with the Java plugin, is it possible to force Gradle to quit after a set number of compilation errors - say, 10 or 20 errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible with Gradle.